# Using FilePond with tui-image-editor in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepond, toast-ui-image-editor

I am trying to get the tui-image editor to work with filepond in Ruby on Rails. I tried a few other editors, but the pricing wasn't acceptable to my wallet.

It seems I need to disable direct upload until the image has been edited, but I'm unable to figure out that step without completely disabling the process step.

It feels like there is only something minor that I am failing to realize.

Below is the code that I do have.

```js
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"

import * as FilePond from "filepond"
import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size"
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type"
import FilePondPluginImageCrop from "filepond-plugin-image-crop"
import FilePondPluginImageEdit from "filepond-plugin-image-edit"
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation"
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview"
import FilePondPluginImageResize from "filepond-plugin-image-resize"
import FilePondPluginImageTransform from "filepond-plugin-image-transform"
import ImageEditor from "tui-image-editor"

ActiveStorage.start()

FilePond.registerPlugin(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview,
  FilePondPluginImageCrop,
  FilePondPluginImageResize,
  FilePondPluginImageTransform,
  FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
  FilePondPluginImageEdit,
)

function openImageEditor(file) {
  // Create a temporary URL for the file
  const editorElement = document.querySelector("#tui-image-editor")
  console.log(editorElement)
  const imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  const imageEditor = new ImageEditor(
    editorElement,
    {
      includeUI: {
        loadImage: {
          path: imageURL,
          name: "event",
        },
        menu: ["shape", "crop"],
        menuBarPosition: "bottom",
      },
      cssMaxWidth: 700,
      cssMaxHeight: 500,
      selectionStyle: {
        cornerSize: 20,
        rotatingPointOffset: 70,
      },
    },
  )
}

function handleEditedImage(imageBlob) {
  // Convert the Blob to a File object, if necessary
  const editedFile = new File([imageBlob], "editedImage.png", { type: "image/png" });

  // Manually add the edited file to FilePond
  FilePond.addFile(editedFile);

  // Now, you can manually trigger FilePond's upload process if it's not automatic
  FilePond.processFile(editedFile);
}

const FilePondRails = {
  allowReorder: true,
  filePosterMaxHeight: 256,
  directUploadUrl: null,
  input: null,
  default_options: {
    onaddfile: (err, fileItem) => {
      openImageEditor(fileItem.file)
    },
    allowFileSizeValidation: true,
    maxFileSize: "10MB",
    labelMaxFileSizeExceeded: "File is too large",
    server: {
      process: (
        fieldName,
        file,
        metadata,
        load,
        error,
        progress,
        abort,
        transfer,
        options,
      ) => {
        const uploader = new DirectUpload(file, FilePondRails.directUploadUrl, {
          directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR: (request) => {
            request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) =>
              progress(event.lengthComputable, event.loaded, event.total),
            )
          },
        })

        uploader.create((errorResponse, blob) => {
          if (errorResponse) {
            error(`Something went wrong: ${errorResponse}`)
          } else {
            const hiddenField = document.createElement("input")
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden")
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id)
            hiddenField.name = FilePondRails.input.name
            document.querySelector("form").appendChild(hiddenField)
            load(blob.signed_id)
          }
        })

        return {
          abort: () => abort(),
        }
      },
      fetch: {
        url: "/filepond/active_storage/fetch",
        method: "POST",
        onload: (response) => {
          return response
        },
        ondata: (response) => {
          return response
        },
      },
      revert: {
        url: "/filepond/active_storage/remove",
      },
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": document.head.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']")
          .content,
      },
    },
  },
  // Convenience method to initialize FilePond based on the way this gem expects things to work
  create: (input) => {
    FilePondRails.directUploadUrl = input.dataset.directUploadUrl
    FilePondRails.input = input

    // Initialize FilePond on our element
    return FilePond.create(input, FilePondRails.default_options)
  },
}

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
  if (document.querySelector(".filepond")) {
    FilePondRails.create(document.querySelector(".filepond"))
  }
  if (document.getElementById("image_preview")) {
    document.getElementById("image_preview").submit()
  }
})

window.FilePond = FilePond
window.FilePondRails = FilePondRails
```